# Can I use the initial columns of A (that I know do not contain a pivot in REF form) as a basis for NulA?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

If I have a matrix A, and I write the solution to Nul$A$ in parametric form of something like, $c_1 \boldsymbol{v_1}, c_2\boldsymbol{v_2},...,c_p\boldsymbol{v_p}$, obviously $\boldsymbol{v_1}, \boldsymbol{v_2}, ... \boldsymbol{v_p}$ form a basis, but can the original non-pivot vectors of A form a basis as well?